# Installing Firefox on EC2 using Lambda Linux Project

Tags: firefox, amazon-ec2, selenium

I'm trying to set up a nodejs+selenium server on ec2.

I got node installed and working and I tried to set up Firefox using the tutorial here:

https://lambda-linux.io/blog/2015/01/28/announcing-firefox-browser-support-for-amazon-linux/

I got it all installed but however, whenever I run firefox, I get this error.

> GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lambda-linux/h5KHo6257pY/KWYhRHfBAwAJ) we have updated the instructions to download the latest version of Firefox. If this still fails with the latest version of Amazon Linux AMI and Firefox, please let us know.

Thank you for using Lambda Linux Project packages.